# Azure. The Run Command Feature of Doesn't work on VM Created From Snapshot

Tags: azure-virtual-machine

We have 2 VMs, VM1 is the original VM, VM2 is created from a Snapshot of VM1.
Run Command runs fine on VM1, but when executed with PowerShell `Invoke-AzVMRunCommand` it times out. When doing "Run command" from Portal no changes (and no timeout) appear.

What can be the reason for that?

We are initiating Run Command via PowerShell:

```
Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName Restore-RG -VMName DB-SLV-IMG-VM-LatestRestore-VM -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath C:\Scripts\Script1.ps1
```

And the contents of Script1.ps1 are:

```
. C:\Scripts\TargetScript.ps1
```

The contents of the TargetScript.ps1 on VM1 and VM2 are:

```
New-Item C:\Scripts\File1
```

Comment: Do you run Azure Custom Script Extension fail or run command fail? Could you show how do you run the Custom Script Extension and the contents of the extension?

Comment: You are right, I wasn't using Azure Custom Script Extension, but rather Run Command. I've edited the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

You could ensure that you follow the correct steps to create the Azure VM from that snapshot.

To create an Azure VM from a snapshot, you need to create a managed disk from a snapshot and then attaching the new managed disk as the OS disk. For more information, see the sample in [Create a VM from a snapshot with PowerShell](https://azurelessons.com/create-azure-virtual-machine-from-a-snapshot/).

After my validation, if Run Command runs fine on VM1, you should see the `Script1.ps1` in such path `C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.CPlat.Core.RunCommandWindows\1.1.5\Downloads` on the target VM.

[image]

Then you create a snapshot at this time and create a managed disk from this snapshot then you create a new Azure VM2 by attaching the new managed disk. You will see the same data on the VM2 as the VM1.
[image]

If you run command for VM2 at this time, the following message will show up unless you remove the `File1` in the path `C:\Scripts\File1`. This is expected.

> The file 'C:\Scripts\File1' already exists.

[image]